# Laravel eager loading 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have this problem with 'eager loading' in laravel.

Im working with 4 tables that are related to each other.

I have these modals:

```
<?php
class AgendaPersonalModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'agenda_personal';

    public function periods() {

        return $this->hasMany(AgendaPersonalPeriodModel::class, 'agenda_id');

    }
}
?>
```

---

```
class AgendaPersonalPeriodModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'agenda_personal_period';


        public function weekdays() {

        return $this->hasMany(AgendaPersonalWeekdaysModel::class, 'period_id');

    }
```

---

```
<?php
class AgendaPersonalWeekdaysModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'agenda_personal_weekdays';


    public function breaks() {

        return $this->hasMany(AgendaPersonalBreakModel::class, 'weekday_id');

    }    

}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
class AgendaPersonalBreakModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'agenda_personal_breaks';
}

?>
```

Now i want to 'get' all the data in one object.

When i do this:

```
$agendaTest = AgendaPersonalModel::with(array('periods', 'periods.weekdays'))->where('id', 1)->first();
```

It works PERFECT

but when i do this:

```
$agendaTest = AgendaPersonalModel::with(array('periods', 'periods.weekdays', 'weekdays.breaks'))->where('id', 1)->first();
```

I get the following error:

```
(1/1) RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [weekdays] on model [App\Models\AgendaPersonalModel].
in RelationNotFoundException.php (line 20)
```

Comment: Do you have a weekdays relationship defined on `AgendaPersonalModel`? Or did you mean to do 'periods.weekdays.breaks'?

Comment: He Josh, it comes down to do: 'periods.weekdays.breaks'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
$agendaTest = AgendaPersonalModel::with(['periods', 'periods.weekdays.breaks'])->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: This will not work. Nested eager loading works only with 1 or 2 levels of relationships.

Comment: GREAT, i tried something like this before but i see my mistake now. This is the best solution in my case, thnks ALOT

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
AgendaPersonalModel::with(['periods', 'periods.weekdays' => function ($q) {
        $q->with('breaks');
    }])->find(1);
```